# JavaScript search algorithm

Tags: javascript, regex, algorithm, search

I'm working on a client-side search system in JavaScript for a project of mine, and am having particular trouble getting the search functionality to behave as one would expect search functionality to behave.

At current, the search terms, sorted in the array `q` and looped round with a `for` loop (so `q[i]` is the current term being dealt with), select words in which they are part of, and also don't have any impact on each other.

These cause two issues.

1. With the first issue, a search for *intro* returns an *Introduction* article, as you might expect, but similarly a search for *con* returns an article on *Conditions*, which isn't really helpful functionality.
2. The second, more serious, issue is that search terms don't effect each other, so a search for `introduction is important for comedians to setup their jokes`, returns "introduction" and "setup" articles as these terms are in the query.

The code snippet which loops through each search word (which is inside a loop which loops round each article) and prioritizes the results, is as follows:

```
rq = new RegExp(q[i], 'gim');
eq = new RegExp("\\b" + escape(q[i]) + "\\b", 'gi');

if (rq.test(title) || rq.test(keywords)) {
    match = true;
    if (title.match(rq) != null) {
        if (title.match(eq) != null) {
            priority += (title.match(eq).length * 5)
        }
        priority += (title.match(rq).length); // Is this wise?
    }
    if (keywords.match(rq) != null) {
        if (keywords.match(eq) != null) {
            priority += (keywords.match(eq).length * 3);
        }
        priority += (keywords.match(rq).length); // Is this wise?
    }
}
```

These behaviors are inevitable with the algorithmic decisions made, however I simply can't think of a better way to do this (and there are obviously better ways out there).
Maybe I'm just over-thinking it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few observations:

(1) "a search for *intro* returns an *Introduction* article, as you might expect, but similarly a search for *cond* returns an article on *Conditions*, which would likely not be what the user was looking for."  I don't understand the difference here.  Looks like two cases of matching a prefix.  Also, the suffix/infix *ion* will match both *Introduction* and *Conditions*, at least with your `rq` regex.

(2) `.match()` here returns an array of matching strings, since you have the `g` modifier set.  If `title` is "The Sound and the Fury", `priority += (title.match(rq).length)` gives twice as muchh `priority` to *the* than to *fury*.  I'm not sure I understand why multiple matches should get more `priority`.  As Florent has mentioned, you might want to treat *the* and *and* as stopwords, lest multiple matches on these unimportant words swamp matches on words you really care about.

(3) You might want to provide options like "all the words in this phrase, in this exact order", "all the words, in any order," and "any of these words."  You're on the right track with `eq`, matching at word boundaries.  Or you might want to explicitly support some kind of stemming or wildcard syntax, so that, for instance, *intro*" matches *Introduction* but *intro* does not.

**Update**

Implementing "all the words, in any order" is straightforward -- you might be overthinking this.  This snippet sets `match` to `true` if all the `q` are found in either `title` or `keywords`, `false` otherwise:

```
var match = true;
for (i = 0; i < q.length; i++) {
    eq = new RegExp("\\b" + escape(q[i]) + "\\b", 'gi');
    if (!eq.test(title)) {
        match = false;
        break;
    }
    if (!eq.test(keywords)) {
        match = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you can do is to ignore commons words such as *the*, *and*, *or*, *a*, etc.

Maybe keywords should be more important than title.

Comment: I've adapted my local copy to get rid of these common words, and this seems to help the system a lot, and after wiping out 'rq' in favour of only exact matching, the problem '1' which I initially outlined is pretty much gone. My problem now mainly lies with interlinking the query terms...

Comment: However after indexing results, you can check for those a an the... In results for  increasing match priority